# To make "implicit payments paypal" must get permission from PayPal' - what does that mean?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Now , my paypal app status is "**Approved Automatically**"

ok, I can not use **chained payapl** because to make **chained paypal** my app must status "**Conditionally Approved**"

i want to know app status "**Approved Automatically**" can use `implicit payments paypal` or not ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get "**Implicit Payments**" permissions for a Live account, you will need to request your APP id (Classic) at https://developer.paypal.com > Applications > My apps > Create and manage Classic API apps. Make sure to select "**Implicit Send Money**" from the Basic Payments options. 
If your APP shows "Approved Automatically" status, I believe you only selected "Send Money".